# Set single product image (main image) and archive thumbnail image as different from each other in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We would like to set the single image and the archive image as different images, mainly because we want to include a .gif in archive (shop, category grid) and a normal png in the single page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your thumbnail

```
<?php echo woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() ?>
```

and for archive page use a custom metabox